Lunar Eclipse in USA
I live in Minnesota, USA and I was wondering when the next total lunar eclipse will be.
Thanks.

Mr Eclipse knows https://eclipsewise.com/eclipse.html

The nice part about lunar eclipses - if you can see the Moon, you can see the eclipse, wherever on Earth you are. For solar eclipses your place means a lot, a total solar eclipce can be seen only in narrow path in specific time.

The next total lunar eclipse will be on March 14, 2025. From your location, you should be able to see the moon be totally eclipsed. The full eclipse will last from 1:26 A.M to 2:31 AM in Central Daylight Time (CDT). You may also want to look at this map of where the lunar eclipse will be visible.
